# Forcing encoding & decoding with Doctrine 2

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, doctrine-orm, latin1

I'm working with a legacy [big ball of mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud) that uses a `latin1` database but works with `utf8` strings. Each time the application reads or writes to database, it decodes or encodes *by hand* and stores `utf8` encoded strings in the `latin1` database.

When writing, it does something like:

```php
$value = utf8_encode("Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn")
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (key) VALUES ($value)")
```

So the stored value is `IÃ±tÃ«rnÃ¢tiÃ´nÃ lizÃ¦tiÃ¸n`

And when reading:

```php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT key FROM table")
$value = utf8_decode($result) // Wich results on "Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn" again
```

How can I manage the same database using Doctrine 2 and respecting that strange behaviour?

The following code will work as expected when used in my `Entity`, but I'm looking for a cleaner and DRY solution.

```
public function setKey($value)
{
    $this->key = utf8_encode($value);
}

public function getKey()
{
    return utf8_decode($this->key);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own custom "string" type and override it's class in `Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type`. `Type::convertToDatabaseValue` and `Type::convertToPHPValue` would be what you want to override.

```
<?php
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\StringType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class Utf8StringType extends StringType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $p)
    {
        // convert from utf8 to latin1
        return mb_convert_encoding($value, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $p)
    {
        // convert from latin1 to utf8
        return mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
    }
}
```

Then put the type into Doctrine with a new name or replace the string type:

```
<?php
\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType('utf8string', 'Utf8StringType');
// replace the default string type
\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::overrideType('string', 'Utf8StringType');
```