# Convert MSSQL output to utf8 in PHP / Symfony

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, encoding, utf-8

I've read that mssql does not support utf8 - the problem is that I need to access values from a database but always get the error: `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`.

So I've tried to configure Symfony to use utf8 when connecting to the mssql database, but this did not work as [dbal docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#pdo-sqlsrv-sqlsrv) tells me for sqlsrv, that there is no charset option.

I'm currently using the following configuration, which failed when the symfony serializer tried to encode a json due to "malformed utf8" (which I can see when outputing by signs like '?').

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    driver:   sqlsrv
    host:     "%database_host%"
    dbname:   "%databaset_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    mapping_types:
      timestamp: string
      ntext: text
```

How can I tell Doctrine to use utf8 for sql server? Is there a way to "intercept" the query to transform the result into valid utf8, or any other way?

I've maybe found an answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112284/forcing-encoding-decoding-with-doctrine-2), but don't know how to implement this in a symfony project.. Maybe you could help me a bit -
Is there a way to hook into the query process and parse the output directly?

Comment: Hi! Check this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28856797/2270041

Comment: Custom String type worked like a charm!

Comment: You are welcome!  Consider to upvote it if you retain it useful!